# Postgres lowering max_connection

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I have a question regarding `max_connections` in `postgresql.conf`.

In the Postgresql documentation, it says it determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. Does it literally mean users connected to it? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of connections.  It is not the number of users, as one user can have many connections concurrently and each one counts against max_connections.  And you can also have many more users than connections, as long as users are not permanently connected.

Comment: Appreciate the concise explanation!

Answer (score 1):

A database connection consists of a TCP (or UNIX socket) network connection to the database machine and a server process on the database machine that serves client queries. You can see active connections in the view `pg_stat_activity`.

That is what is limited by `max_connections`.

Do not confuse concurrent users *in your application* with concurrent database connections. If you use connection pooling as you should, a database connection can handle requests from many application users.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it thoroughly. The postgresql documentation was a bit confusing!